# How can I play the system's special sound? For example the drag-n-drop sound

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio

On the Mac, when a drag-n-drop has finished,a special sound will be played. How can I play the same sound programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use a system call to tell the system to play that sound, but I think that an easy solution is to find the sound file on your system and use it in you program. ;)

Comment: I found some of them in system/library/sounds.But the drag-n-drop sound is not there,any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like [Audio Hijack Pro](http://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/) to record the system audio while you perform a copy operation.  Then you can use the resulting audio file.

I can't say this is legal, seeing that you'd be using copyrighted resources.